# http app unreachable from tailscale and funnel and k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, tailscale

I get an http app (written in rust) which serve 2 routes on port **3000**:

1. `/`, for serving static file
2. `/health`, which return a simple string: "Ok"

When testing, everuthing works, both routes are accessibles from localhost.

I dockerise my app, expose port 3000, everythink work as expected.

I create a chart with `helm create`.

My deployment port look like :

```
ports:
  - name: http
    containerPort: 3000
    protocol: TCP
```

My service is

```
 spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
```

I set 443 as port because of ingress.

Now I use an ingress with a vpn (Tailscale) to expose my service with funnel

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    tailscale.com/funnel: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: tailscale
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: mysvc
            port:
              number: 443
```

All pods are running and I can see, into ingress description, the backend `mysvc:443` with an ip.

I try to reach my http `/health` route with curl and tailnet name: `curl -v subroute.tailnetname.ts.net:443/health`.

But I get:

```
Host speedupdate.marlin-atlas.ts.net:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: 2a00:dd80:3a::131
* IPv4: 176.58.88.82
*   Trying 176.58.88.82:443...
* Connected to speedupdate.marlin-atlas.ts.net (176.58.88.82) port 443
> GET /health HTTP/1.1
> Host: speedupdate.marlin-atlas.ts.net:443
> User-Agent: curl/8.6.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Closing connection
```

I don't inderstand why? Expected answer is the string `Ok`

I inspect proxy pod created by tailscale, and get no error log, no http call logs too.

So what is wrong ?

Update : some logs from pod proxy

```
2024/03/19 16:48:39 Drop: TCP{[fd7a:115c:a1e0:ab12:4843:cd96:625a:9516]:52274 > [fd7a:115c:a1e0::17df:370d]:60438} 80 no rules matched                                           

2024/03/19 16:48:39 Accept: TCP{[fd7a:115c:a1e0:ab12:4843:cd96:625a:9516]:52274 > [fd7a:115c:a1e0::17df:370d]:60438} 72 tcp non-syn

2024/03/19 16:48:39 Accept: TCP{[fd7a:115c:a1e0:ab12:4843:cd96:625a:9516]:52274 > [fd7a:115c:a1e0::17df:370d]:60438} 354 tcp non-syn

2024/03/19 16:48:40 http: proxy error: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

Update 2: I can reach my app with `kubectl port-forward mysvc`

Comment: --https=<port> Specifies the port to listen on. For [Funnel](https://tailscale.com/kb/1311/tailscale-funnel#use-https-and-http-servers), you must use one of the allowed ports: 443, 8443, or 10000.

To serve as a reverse proxy to a local backend, provide the location of the <target> argument. The location to the local service can be expressed as a port number (for example, 3000)

Comment: I deploy tailscale with k8s operator, we cannot configure funnel

Comment: Have you go through this official [doc](https://tailscale.com/kb/1236/kubernetes-operator#ingress-resource)

Comment: @DavidMaze I have edited my answer. Thanks for suggesting me to edit the answer I welcome your kind gesture for continuously supporting this community

Comment: Yes I follow the doc during install. You can see my ingress with annotations enabling funnel

Comment: There is a [feature request](https://github.com/tailscale/tailscale/issues/11330) about this issue

Comment: curl -v https://myhostname is not an https request ?

Comment: Have you update the ACLs for your tailnet to allow Kubernetes Operator proxy services to use Tailscale Funnel.

Comment: Yes I get ```nodeAttrs": [
  {
   // Funnel policy, which lets tailnet members control Funnel
   // for their own devices.
   // Learn more at https://tailscale.com/kb/1223/tailscale-funnel/
   "target": ["tag:k8s"],
   "attr":   ["funnel"],
  },
 ],``` into acl

Comment: Note that even if your policy has the funnel attribute assigned to autogroup:member (which is the default), you still need to add it to the tag used by proxies, since autogroup:member does not include tagged nodes.


https://www.reddit.com/r/Tailscale/comments/17qwmjx/kubernetes_operator_funnel_not_working/

Comment: I have to add autogroup:member to target ? ( I try and still get issue)

Comment: what is the exact issue ? can you please explain

Comment: **http: proxy error: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake**This error indicates that it was due to HTTPS_PROXY not having the correct variable (https instead of http)

Comment: I guess you need to update the Ingress rule **backend.service.port.number** field to 3000 

This ensures the Ingress routes traffic on port 3000 to your service which is correct port for your application

Comment: Finally you're right. I delete my ingress (to restart from scratch) modify ingress port to use 3000, re apply manifest and work as expected !! Thank you a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It looks like the problem you are having has to do with the way your Ingress is set up with the tailscale funnel.**

As per this official [doc](https://tailscale.com/kb/1236/kubernetes-operator#ingress-resource) on tailscale when you are exposing your kubernetes ingress resources to tailnet using tailscale kubernetes operator, these ingress resources only support TLS and can only be exposed over HTTPS.

**To properly configure your tailscale deployment follow these steps mentioned in the official documentation:**

> Edit the Ingress resource you want to expose to use the Ingress class
> tailscale:
>
> Set spec.ingressClassName to tailscale.
>
> Set tls.hosts to the desired host name of the Tailscale node. Only the
> first label is used. See custom machine names for details.
>
> For example, to expose an Ingress resource nginx to your tailnet:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
> kind: Ingress
> metadata:
>   name: nginx
> spec:
>   defaultBackend:
>     service:
>       name: nginx
>       port:
>         number: 80
>   ingressClassName: tailscale
>   tls:
>   - hosts:
>     - nginx
> ```
>
> The backend is HTTP by default. To use HTTPS on the backend, either
> set the port name to https or the port number to 443:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
> kind: Ingress
> metadata:
>   name: nginx
> spec:
>   defaultBackend:
>     service:
>       name: nginx
>       port:
>         name: https
>   ingressClassName: tailscale
> ---
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>   name: nginx
> spec:
>   ports:
>   - name: https
>     port: 443
>     targetPort: 443
>   type: ClusterIP
> ```
>
> In the service definition which you have mentioned above instead of
> giving the port number you have mentioned `http` for the `targetPort`
> this might also be an issue. So, correct your service definition and
> the proper port number.
>
> ```
> spec:
>   type: ClusterIP
>   ports:
>     - port: 443
>       targetPort: <port number>
>       protocol: TCP
>       name: http
> ```

Although the Ingress rule targets port 443, your service exposes port 3000 internally. Although you may be using a port for TLS termination with Tail Scale, communication between the Ingress and your service should take place on port 3000. Thus, change the backend service port number column for the Ingress rule to 3000.

This guarantees that traffic from the Ingress is routed to port 3000 on your service, where your application is listening. Verify again that the [Tail Scale Funnel setup](https://tailscale.com/kb/1311/tailscale-funnel#use-https-and-http-servers) is configured to forward traffic on  port 443(HTTPS) to the internal service port 3000 (HTTP).

Try utilizing **curl localhost:3000/health** to access the application directly from within the K8S cluster and **kubectl exec** into a pod to determine whether the problem is with your application or the Ingress settings.

Comment: This answer seems to be principally links to documentation.  Can you [edit] it to include the concrete steps the asker should take?

Comment: funnel only listen on ports 443, 8443 and 1000 https://tailscale.com/kb/1223/funnel#limitations. So I have to do ```spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: mysvc
      port:
        number: 443```

Comment: @DavidMaze I have edited my answer. Thanks for suggesting me to edit the answer 

I welcome your kind  gesture for continuously supporting this community